# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API Cors blocked only into POST

Tags: post, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my `Program.cs` file:

```
using BackendTemplate.Utils;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyOrigin();
}));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ApiResponse<string> Post([FromBody] UsrUser user)
{
    // .....
}
```

Only the `POST` generates a CORS error; the `GET` works correctly.

This is my error on Angular console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mydns/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I cannot understand how to solve this problem, is the first time this happens to me.

Comment: Try it in postman first. CORS issues are often a symptom of another underlying exception that can be in the pipeline before CORS or the routes are configured. Test in isolation using postman first to see what is going on.

Comment: Try to add the    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]  inside the controller to see if this works or note.